# Adding % sign without affecting my calculation

Tags: c#

I'm doing the following calculation: `0.697 * 100` in C# to get a percentage
in that same formula i'd like to add a % sign without it affecting the calculation simply as a plain text character.

There must be a way to include that sign without it considering 100% but instead 100 (plus just the sign%)

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: :( okay. that's too bad lol

Comment: You seem to have some other troubles (from comments in the answers), please post your code, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `%` character to a percentage is something you do when presenting it to the user. So, you add it when displaying the info:

```
float perc = 0.697 * 100;
System.out.println(String.Format("{0} %", perc));
```

Comment: Thank you @Bart Friederichs, I think im running into a problem because my web-application module i'm using does this through boolean expressions? 

Putting in that code just shows up empty.

Comment: @AlexP I fixed a minor typo, but this code is fine. If yours doesn't work, it might be something completely different. Read your errors and logs carefully and when you really cannot figure it out, feel free to ask here again.

Comment: Thank you for the help and quick response

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return a string then?

```
public string Calculate(double x, double y) {
    double result = x * y;
    string returnResult = $"{result}%";
    return returnResult;
}

public string Calculate(double x, double y) {
    double result = x * y;
    string returnResult = String.Format(result + "{0}", "%");
    return returnResult;
}
```

Comment: What is that `$"{result}%"` syntax? The .NET fiddle doesn't seem to accept it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs It is C#6 string interpolation syntax.  To use it in .Net Fiddle you have to switch it to the Roslyn compiler

Comment: @BrianRogers I tried that and that works yes. Cool, I learned today!

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm thanks for the answer. When i paste that into my webapp it just shows up empty. I think I might have mis-typed out my question title. I believe it's using boolean expressions.

Comment: What's blank? Can you give me more detail? This takes a double and makes it into a string with a appended '%' after. Not sure how it can be empty.

Comment: I'm using a CMS with a module that gives me a box where I can enter a calculation using tokens that are replaced with values from my DB so IE: `[percentage] * 100` gives me a correct value but I cannot add the % sign to the end of that.

Comment: It mentiones: Compute a numeric value by referencing grid fields and tokens. For example, [Qty] * [Price] + [MyCustomToken:ThatReturnsTaxes].
This is a server side expression (C# and My Tokens. See More examples.)

Comment: I'm not writing this in VS just on my web-app. I might have mis-categorized this post. Apologies in advance.

Comment: I'm not following. If you're writing in C#, then you can interpolate strings. If it's not C#, then you shouldn't have categorized this as a C# question.

Comment: Worst case you can just do this `return x* y + "%";`

Comment: Yes, I realize this now. The help text mentioned (This is a serer side experssion (C#)) So I thought it was asking for a c# syntax.

My mistake